# Adding a constant on probit models in Python

Tags: python, statsmodels

I'm using the statsmodel package to run a probit model, problem is that at 0 the model always predicts 0.5. I followed directions I found online to add a constant array into my input data using statsmodels.api.add_constant(), but then doing model.fit().predict() returns errors, does anybody know what I might be doing wrong?
x is a vector containing my input data and y is my response vector.
I also use sm for statsmodels.api and p for probit

```
X=sm.add_constant(x)
model=p(y,X).fit()
```

I then run model.predict(sm.add_constant(.5)) and I get

```
ValueError: shapes (1,1) and (2,) not aligned: 1 (dim 1) != 2 (dim 0)
```

Comment: There is not enough information, show your code and the traceback. Did you add a constant also to the `x` for `predict(x)`?

Comment: Sorry about that, I added a little more information to the original post now.

Comment: check `sm.add_constant(.5)` separately from predict. My guess is that it cannot take a scalar value, i.e. try `sm.add_constant([[.5]])`

Comment: The previous lines of the traceback show the code location of the exception. Those can tell you where it breaks, e.g. in `add_constant` or in `predict`